React-native IOS build PhaseScriptExecution error
PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Generate\ Specs /var/root/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AwesomeProject-ctijgwfuqsfcgvbuoytyyjefesnx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-Codegen.build/Script-46EB2E00013660.sh (in target 'React-Codegen' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)
Build react-native project with yarn ios and expect this issue.I search from some blogs and forums but i can't see resolve.

Did you check this?
They suggest running cd ios && RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED=1 pod install after adding new packages

I have the same error, I asked many React Native developer about it, no one could solve it...
